# Connecting PowerBI Desktop to same Oracle instance twice with different credentials

Tags: oracle, powerbi

We have to connect to 2 schemas on the same instance.

When I set up the server connection the first time using this server syntax.

```
PARIEL=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=SESKOVLGDBP23.mycompany.net)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=PARIEL)))
```

I am asked for the credentials.

When I come to create a different connection to the same instance, but using different credentials...it sees that the server is the same, and just automatically logs me in with the old credentials.

Surely you can have 2 connections to the same instance using 2 different credentials?  We do this in Spotfire all the time, so assume it is possible.

Thanks

Comment: It appears that this is not possble (you probably saw this, https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/connect-to-the-same-database-with-2-different-users/m-p/7695#M1123). Perhaps pinging MS support might be able to confirm this is not possible. The link I provide provides an alternate way to approach this.

Comment: That’s a major issue, they expect people to only want to access one database on a server?!